# Creating a windows named pipe with security permissions

Tags: java, kernel32

I want to create a named pipe from a java process and give full permissions to a user from different security group to connect to the pipe and use it.

The way i create the pipe is:

```
INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);

pipe = INSTANCE.CreateNamedPipeA( 
        fullPipeName,             // pipe name 
        Kernel32.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
        Kernel32.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
        Kernel32.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
        Kernel32.PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
        Kernel32.PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
        BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size 
        BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size 
        0,                        // client time-out 
        Pointer.NULL);
```

I know the last parameter of the CreateNamedPipeA method is for security, but i have no idea how i should use it.

Comment: did you ever figure it out?